# regex match file name in a path

Tags: regex

I am trying to match the file name in a path. For example:

```
/path/test/index.html
```

I would want to match `index.html`
However I also can have a path with no `/` so the path could be

```
index.html
```

and would want to match `index.html`

I have the following to match the first case and can grab it with a group.

```
.*/([^/]+)
```

But how can I also match a file name when the only thing in the path is the file name?

Comment: What language are you using?  This might not be a job for a regex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is probably no need to have anything but `[^/]+$` unless you want to
match the entire line and your engine matcher requires it.

Answer (score 1):

There is usually more than one way to do a regex, and also that there are often edge cases that end up complicating a simple task.

If you want to match any/ every valid file name in a string then perhaps:

```
[A-Za-z0-9_-]+\.?[A-Za-z0-9]*
```

or (since you can have a file named *ConfigurationFile.txt.bac* for example)...

```
[A-Za-z0-9_-\.]+\.?[A-Za-z0-9]*
```

But that is not what you want because each directory name is a valid file name... so...
this will match only valid file names with an extension.

```
[A-Za-z0-9_-]+\.[A-Za-z0-9]+
```

or

```
[A-Za-z0-9_-\.]+\.[A-Za-z0-9]+
```

Clearly there are many options. The AA(accepted answer) only matches any string in a path that is at the end of the path. It does not match a file name without a path. The AA may well do for the OP. It is helpful to me to be able to match any file name within a string.

There are always edge cases, for example in my case I am still matching version numbers with this regex. I have a work around for my case but I am getting too specific.

Answer (score 0):

Make the `.*/` into an optional group:

```
(?:.*/)?([^/]+)
```